# panda error - file not getting uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pandastream

I am trying to embed a video in my app and am using the gem panda '1.6.0' for this. I followed the pandastream integrate with rails guide and have the following code:

```
  controllers:
  -------------

  class BoothVideosController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :init_booth_video

   def show
    @original_video = @video.panda_video
    @h264_encoding = @original_video.encodings["h264"]
    render :template => 'booth_video/booth_video', :layout => 
                        'sponsored_group_manage_sub_menu'
   end

   def new
     @video = BoothVideo.new
     render :layout => 'sponsored_group_manage_sub_menu'
   end

   def create
     @video = BoothVideo.create!(params[:video])
     redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @video.id 
   end

   def init_booth_video
     @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
     @video=@group.booth_video
   end
 end


   class PandaController < ApplicationController
       def authorize_upload
         payload = JSON.parse(params['payload'])
         upload = Panda.post('/videos/upload.json', {
         file_name: payload['filename'],
         file_size: payload['filesize'],
        profiles: "h264",
       })
        render :json => {:upload_url => upload['location']}
      end
   end


 model:
 ------
 class BoothVideo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :group
   validates_presence_of :panda_video_id

   def panda_video
      @panda_video ||= Panda::Video.find(panda_video_id)
   end
  end


 View
 -----

  <% content_for(:page_title, "Create a New Booth Video") -%>
  <% form_for(:booth_video,:url => group_booth_video_path, :html => {:id => 
                                  "new_booth_video", :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <h5>New Booth Video</h5>
  <fieldset>
 <input type="hidden" name="panda_video_id"/>
     <label for="title">Title</label><br />
     <%= f.text_field :title, :size => 32, :placeholder => "Title for the new booth 
                           video" %><br /><br />
    <div class='progress'>
            <span id="progress-bar" class='bar'></span>
    </div>
    <div id="browse">Choose file</div>
    <%=f.submit "Upload video" %>
   <% end %>
```

I have also included the js for panda uploader in my application.js file.
I am able to see my file uploader but when I actually browse and select a file, it does not actually get loaded - also no progress is indicated in the progress bar.

1. Why is the video not getting uploaded?
2. The create action mentions params[:video] in the tutorial but there is no param in the 
   'new' form for the uploaded video-how will it recognize this?

Please help! Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you ever get your panda uploader to work?